# Firebase first login or signup events

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication in my app. I want to redirectUser to a particular page if the user signs in for the first time or just signs up. Can somebody please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I you are using a identity provider, such as Google Sign-In or Facebook Login the  only way to do that is to store an atributte where you kept the information needed to check if is the first login or not.

If you're using a password based account you can call the function to redirect after creating the user.

```js
firebase.auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(() => { 
    //MyFunction
  }).catch((error) => { 
    //Handle the error
  });
```

Comment: Super late to this thread, but for anyone still needing this answer, there is an alternative for federated logins. In the "user" auth object sent from Firebase, you can compare `if(user.metadata.creationTime === user.metadata.lastSignInTime) { doSomethingForFirstTimeUsers() }`. This prevents creating an additional field for each user in your DB that will only be used once.

Comment: Hi @JacobK, thanks for the tip. However, I see a downside to this approach as a user could logout before going through the onboarding screens we expect him to go though during his first login. A database flag remains the most reliable way to address this imho.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the best way is to use Firebase Authentication Triggers (Cloud functions).

Firebase accounts will trigger user creation events for Cloud Functions when:

- A user creates an email account and password.
- A user signs in for the first time using a federated identity provider.
- The developer creates an account using the Firebase Admin SDK.
- A user signs into a new anonymous auth session for the first time. A Cloud

*Functions event is not triggered when a user signs in for the first time using a custom token.*

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation

Kudos to this (open) issue on Github:
https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/137